# ant: list folders on command line

Tags: command-line, ant, variables, directory

I'm new to ant. I'm looking to a way to do this

I have a folder, with a variable number of subfolders. Suppose subfolders are s1,s2,s3...,sN (N is not known)

I need to create and execute this command line

java -jar myjar.jar s1\ s2\ s3\ ... sN\

I would like to use standard  task, but I do not know how to list folders on the command line.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Alberto

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'fileset' type is what you're looking for:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

The 'jar' task can work with implicit filesets, or you can define custom filesets within the jar task.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

See the examples at the bottom of the jar page.

Answer (score 0):

You cac create an ant custom task which get the parent dir, a dirset or a patternset and writes all the names into an ant property

See more about it here http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html